# PIC MICROs : How to convert a float in separate characters array?

Tags: c++, c, microcontroller, pic

Im getting a float var from an ADC reading and conversion, I need to display the digits separately in a 7 segment display, thats why i need the numbers separately.

float var =12.34; // i need a way to convert this

int rb[1,2,3,4]; // into this

If it was int it would be very easy using divisions and mod, but i think it has to be a more elegant way to do it . isnt it?

Any help is welcome.

Thanks for watching

Comment: why do you think that `1,2,3,4` represents `12.34`, maybe it `1.234` or `123.4`?

Comment: Don't you know what language you're using?

Comment: `int rb[1,2,3,4];` is neither C nor C++.

Comment: im using ccs, with the PCW compiler, then simulating it on proteus...

Comment: referring to the first question yes good point but i have it externally controlled because its gonna be always two digits after dot. and a max of 2 before the dot

Comment: personally, converting the float to string would do most of the work for you; then its trivial to get the int array from

Comment: @TapVelvet then multiple by 100.0 and cast to int - then you know what to do

Comment: Only 2 decimal points needed?  I think that was only for his example...

Answer (score 2):

First you need to convert the float into an string, as you didn't told us which compiler are using, I assume C30, [here](http://www.microchip.com/forums/m183763.aspx) you have the code for ftoa (convert float to string). If you're using another compiler like C18 look at their forums, there are lots of implementations (or just convert the one for C30).

```
unsigned char floatAsString[32];
ftoa(var, floatAsString);
```

Next, you need to create your array, you need to check if the float has decimals or not to skip the dot for the decimal places:

```
int len;

if((int)var == var)
    len = strlen(floatAsString);
else
    len = strlen(floatAsString) - 1;
```

Then, finally you can fill an int array;

```
int theArray[len];
unsigned char tmpBuffer[2];
tmpBuffer[1] = '\0';

int j;
int i;

unsigned char foundDot;

for(j = 0; j < len; j++)
{
    if(foundDot)
        i = j - 1;
    else
        i = j;

    unsigned char theChar = floatAsString[j];

    if(theChar == '.')
    {
        foundDot = 1;
        continue;
    }

    tmpBuffer[0] = theChar;
    theArray[i] = atoi(tmpBuffer);
}
```

Comment: Gosh, after writting this monster the user added a ton of delimitations to the question which makes this answer the less optimal one.. I hate when these things happen. If we check the comments, then just multiplying by 100 as @Lashane said would reduce a lot this code.

Comment: I just have checked this code and i have an error in the second line saying ftoa is an undefined identifier, i guess im missing a library, am i

Comment: sorry , it says number of bites is out of range on the line 51  ...       unsigned int    mantissa_lo : 16;

Comment: That's because the code is for C30 compiler, as I said, if you use another compiler you must seek for the correct implementation of ftoa. Anyway, read my first comment, if you just need two decimals, then multiply your float by 100, convert it to an integer and then use itoa, but you must modify this code to skip the dot comprobation and so on.

Comment: Check this: https://www.ccsinfo.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=50946 look at the end, there shows how to use sprintf to achieve the same result as ftoa.